# non- static function to create the thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am creating application in .NET which can be used at server side. My application has C++ part also. In one of the c++  class I need to create a thread which should run through the lifetime of the object.
I am using CreateThread function to create new thread.

The issue is, it requires a static function as parameter to run the thread. As I want to deploy it at server end, I don’t want to use static function to be used for thread. I want to use a member function of the object to be used for this method.

Is there any better way to create the thread

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass a member function pointer to `CreateThread`, but you can pass a non-member function which forwards to the member function.

You can pass an argument to `CreateThread` which gets passed to your function. Use this to pass the instance of your class through:

```
struct foo
{
    void thread_func();

    static DWORD CALLBACK thread_func_thunk(void *arg)
    {
        ((foo*)arg)->thread_func();
    }
};

foo fooinst;
CreateThread(nullptr, 0, foo::thread_func_thunk, (void*)&fooinst, 0, nullptr)
```

Comment: +1, despite 'thread_func_thunk' :)  foo could be abstract, then you can add foo in your inheritance chain, implementing thread_func() how you want, though you should then call it 'Task', or the like).

Comment: I have one doubt, This thread suppose to run through the whole lifetime of the object which created it. During that time if another object access the thread_func_thunk function, then will it cause any problem or the two created thread will run side by side safely?

Comment: The entire sample I posted is thread-safe. It's up to you to make `thread_func` safe and/or call it with separate instances.